# how many epoch for training 1k images

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

am doing training for detecting the objects using yolov3 but i face some problem when i set batch_size > 1 it causes me cuda out of memory so i searched in google to see another solution found it depends on my GPU (GTX 1070 8G) .

may be the number of epoch is  high and it require to be optimized .

maybe the epoch number should be decreased? and for training 1k images and 200 pic for validations .

what is best epoch should i set to avoid overfitting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your model's overfitting wont depend on the no. of epochs you set.....
since you hav made a val split in your data, make sure that your **train loss - val loss OR train acc - val acc** is nearly the same.This will assure that your model is not overfitting

Comment: i implemented code from github not figured out where ican check this calculations . if i put too high epoch this will affect in my model?

Comment: @memi Just save your model using "if condition " when the above case is met ...